# Insert Custom Options of product with script

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, magento

I have a script for inserting a product custom options in Magento. Its working fine for single custom option, if there are multiple custom options for a single product then it insert only single custom option and discard others.

```
 <?php
// Report all PHP errors (see changelog)
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

// Include Magento application
require_once ( "../app/Mage.php" );
umask(0);

// Initialize Magento
Mage::app("default");
$start = 0;
$totalno =1000;
$row = 0;
$sku = 0;
$baseRowoption = array();
$myarrayoption = array();
if (($handle = fopen("custom_option-final.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle,",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            if($row == 0){
                $baseRowoption[$c]=$data[$c];
            }else{
                if($c==0){
                    $sku=$data[$c];
                }
                $myarrayoption[$sku][$row][$baseRowoption[$c]]=$data[$c];
            }
        }
        $row++;
        if($row > $totalno){
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

$myarrayoptionfinal = array();
foreach($myarrayoption as $key=>$myarrayoption1){
    //if($key != "smartek-rx3044"){ break; }
    foreach($myarrayoption1 as $myarrayoption11){
        $myarrayoptionfinal[$key][$myarrayoption11['option_title']]['input_type'] = $myarrayoption11['input_type'];
        $myarrayoptionfinal[$key][$myarrayoption11['option_title']]['required'] = $myarrayoption11['required'];
        $myarrayoptionfinal[$key][$myarrayoption11['option_title']]['sort_order'] = $myarrayoption11['sort_order'];
        $myarrayoptionfinal[$key][$myarrayoption11['option_title']]['row_title'][] = $myarrayoption11['row_title'];
        $myarrayoptionfinal[$key][$myarrayoption11['option_title']]['row_price'][] = $myarrayoption11['row_price'];
        $myarrayoptionfinal[$key][$myarrayoption11['option_title']]['row_price_type'][] = $myarrayoption11['row_price_type'];
        $myarrayoptionfinal[$key][$myarrayoption11['option_title']]['row_sku'][] = $myarrayoption11['row_sku'];
        $myarrayoptionfinal[$key][$myarrayoption11['option_title']]['row_sort_order'][] = $myarrayoption11['row_sort_order'];
    }

}

echo "<pre>";
echo "total No : ".count($myarrayoptionfinal);
echo "<br />";
//print_r($myarrayoptionfinal);
$i=0;
foreach($myarrayoptionfinal as $keys=>$myarrayoptionfinal1){
    if($i<$start){
        $i++;       continue;   
    }
    echo "<br />".$i."--->";
    $i++;
    echo $keys."--->";

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$keys);
    if($product){
     foreach ($product->getProductOptionsCollection() as $option)
    {   
         $optionsData = $option->getData();
         $optionsData['is_delete'] = 1;
         $product->setProductOptions(array($option->getId() => $optionsData));
         $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
         $product->save();
    }}else{
        continue;
    }
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$keys); 
    print_r($product->getData("entity_id")); 
    foreach($myarrayoptionfinal1 as $keysub=>$myarrayoptionfinal11){
        $subarray = array();
        foreach($myarrayoptionfinal11['row_title'] as $keysub1=>$myarrayoptionfinal111){
            $subarray[]=array(
                        'is_delete'     => 0,
                        'title'         => $myarrayoptionfinal111,
                        'price_type'    => $myarrayoptionfinal11['row_price_type'][$keysub1],
                        'price'         => $myarrayoptionfinal11['row_price'][$keysub1],
                        'sku'           =>  $keys.'_'.$myarrayoptionfinal11['row_sku'][$keysub1],
                        'sort_order'    => $myarrayoptionfinal11['row_sort_order'][$keysub1],
                        'option_type_id'=> -1,
                    );
        }

        $required = false;
        if($myarrayoptionfinal11["required"] == 1) $required = true;
        $opt = array(
            'is_delete'         => 0,
            'is_require'        => $required,
            'previous_group'    => '',
            'title'             => $keysub,
            'type'              => $myarrayoptionfinal11["input_type"],
            'price_type'        => '',
            'price'             => '',
            'sort_order'        => $myarrayoptionfinal11["sort_order"],
            /** array of values for this option **/
            'values'            => $subarray,
            );
    }
    try {
            //print_r($opt);
            $option = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')
                ->setProduct($product)
                ->addOption($opt)
                ->saveOptions();
            $product->setHasOptions(1);
            $product->save();
        }
    catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception 2: '.$e->getMessage()."\n";
            continue;
        } 
}
```

Comment: brar ,can please check this....http://www.apptha.com/blog/how-to-programmatically-adddelete-custom-options-in-magento/

Comment: Hi , Can you please check this. http://www.solvingmagento.com/adding-product-custom-options-to-products-in-magento/

Comment: @Brar : One of the above two links would surely work for you man. Let us know your response and yes we are here to help always. :)

Comment: thanks @Chiragit007 and @ Amit Bera , i am trying to solve this  with above links.

Comment: Okay Man, Let us know your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Add custom option to multiple products is quite difficult because there are multiple type custom option in magento like (dropdown, text etc.) also you will found in each custom option multiple values which you need to handle.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-option-manger.html

This extension provides exact functionality multiple custom options for multiple products.